# Markov Chain: classify states of finite Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

I can easily see the states of this MC, recurrent and transient if I graph them, but how do I prove that a state is recurrent or transient. My book refers to probability to ever returning to state $j$ starting with $j$ to differentiate states.

STATES: 0,1,2,3,4

$$P =
\pmatrix{0&  0& 0.5 &0.5 &0 \\
0& 0.1& 0 &0.4 &0.5 \\
0.9 &0  &0.1 &0 &0\\
0 &0  &1 &0 &0\\
0.05 &0 &0.05 &0 &0.9\\}$$

From mathematica: recurrent states: {0,2,3}
Transient: {1},{4}

Comment: Most transitions matrices are square

Answer (score 2):

Firstly separate the states in communication classes. There are two communication classes 
which are determined as follows.

1. Start from state $0$. Which states can you visit and then return to state $0$? You can make following transitions $$0\xrightarrow{0.5} 2 \xrightarrow{0.9} 0$$ So $0$ and $2$ communicate, which means that they belong to the same communication class. In symbols $$0\leftrightarrow 2$$ In contrast if you make the transition $$0\xrightarrow{0.5} 3$$ then you can not return from state $3$. Therefore $0$ and $3$ belong to different communication classes.
2. Start from state $1$.  Which states can you visit and then return to state $1$? You can make following transitions $$1\xrightarrow{0.5} 4 \xrightarrow{0.05} 1$$ So $1$ and $4$ communicate, which means that they belong to the same communication class. In symbols $$1\leftrightarrow 4$$ In contrast if you make the transition $$1\xrightarrow{0.4} 3$$ then you can not return from state $3$. Therefore $1$ and $3$ belong to different communication classes.
3. Do the classes $C_1=\{0,2\}$ and $C_2=\{1,4\}$ communicate? The answer is no, because starting from $C_1$ we can never go to $C_2$ but starting from $C_2$ we will land in $C_1$ eventually and never return.
4. Finally, state $3$ is absorbing, which means that whenever you go there you stay there for ever. So, this is the only recurrent state.

In sum, classes $C_1=\{0,2\}$ and $C_2=\{1, 4\}$ are transient and $C_3=\{3\}$ is recurrent. To see that $C_1$ is transient and obviously in different class than state $3$ ask whether it is possible to visit $C_1$ for ever. The answer is no, since after landing for the first time in $C_3$ you will never return... By definition, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Recurrence) *A state i is said to be transient if, given that we start in state i, there is a non-zero probability that we will never return to i.*

Comment: as you correctly pointed I missed a row. I believe there are actually 2 transient and one recurrent state.

Comment: and the remaining 2 states? There are 4 transient states (class C2) and 1 recurrent state (class C1) or not?

Comment: From mathematica: recurrent states: {0,2,3} Transient: {1},{4}

Comment: @darkblue I edited my answer. I had not the whole matrix when I wrote it...

Comment: @darkblue States 0 and 2 are not reccurent since there is positive probability that you will never return to them... You have entered something mistakenly in mathematica

Answer (score 1):

There are some common (and very useful) results concerning recurrence and transitivity of states which you might know and/or could use:

- All states in an irreducible set are either all recurrent or all transient.
- State $i$ is transient if and only if
  \begin{equation}
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_{ii}^{(n)} < \infty
  \end{equation}
- State $i$ is recurrent if and only if
  \begin{equation}
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_{ii}^{(n)} = \infty
  \end{equation}
  where $p_{ii}^{(n)} = P(X_n = i\,\,|\,\,X_0 = i)$.

Comment: thank you. I'm aware of these theorems. However, I'm not sure how they help me here..

Comment: Other very useful results in your case is that any open class is transient and any finite closed class is recurrent. In that case you immedeatly get the desired result. Otherwise take $i=1$ for example. Since there are no transitions from $i\in\{0,2,3,4\}$ to $1$ we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_{11}^{(n)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}0.1^n = \frac{0.1}{1-0.1} < \infty$ so state 1 is transient by the second bullet point.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple algorithm: let $P$ the transition matrix.

1. let $A=I + P$, $j = 1$
2. replace each non $0$ entry by $1$
3. replace $A$ by $A^2$, $j$ by $2j$
4. Go back to $2.$ until $j\ge n$

Then the graph is connected iff every entry of $A$ is $1$.

At each iteration, at the end of step $4.$ the non zero entries of $A$ are the state you can go to with $\le j$ transitions.

Comment: is there a name for this approach?

Comment: It is related to graph theory. If you have to write it for a computer, use logical operators for a more efficient algorithm (for example, stop to compute $\sum a_{ij}b_{jk}$ as soon as $a_{ij}b_{jk}\neq 0$ for a certain k).

Comment: no, i need to prove it by hand :( this is why i'm struggling

Comment: do you understand how the algo works? by hand, the best approach remains to make the graph.

Comment: @Stefanos, From mathematica: recurrent states: {0,2,3}
Transient: {1},{4}